# What is the time duration for obtaining a short stay scientist visa for France?

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, indian-citizens

I wish to apply for a short stay visa for France as a scientist and for this, my host institution is providing me with a protocole d'accueil document. In how many days, after the submission of protocole d'accueil and other necessary documents at the French consulate in my country, will the visa be sanctioned?

Answer (score 2):

The processing time is different for each country and consulate where you might apply.

For India, the official French government web site [advises](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/in):

> - For short-stay visas, if you hold an Indian passport and are born in India, you must submit your application a minimum of 5 days prior to your scheduled departure. However, the processing time to issue a visa is 48 hours in Delhi, Mumbai, Kolkata, Puducherry and 78 hours in other cases.
> - If you submit your application in Kathmandu, you must submit it a minimum of 15 days bprior to your scheduled departure.
>
> You can not submit an application more than 3 months before the scheduled departure.

You *should* submit your application as soon as possible, and not wait until the last minute. If there are delays in processing the visa application, you might miss your departure.

You can [track the status of your visa application](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/track-your-application-status) also on the French government site, depending on the method by which you applied. I believe that VFS is used in India and they will also send you email and SMS messages if you ask for them at the time you apply for the visa.

Comment: I will be submitting my documents at the French consulate in New Delhi. The purpose of my visit is a research internship and I will be applying for a short stay scientist/researcher VISA for which "protocole d'accueil" document is provided by the host institute. So, is there any advantage of this special provision? Is the VISA processing time for such a VISA same as a normal VISA or is it faster?

Comment: @Brihaspati This is all of the official information that is available. You might get a more specific estimate from VFS at the time you deliver your application package to the VFS office. As always you should apply as early as is practical, just in case there is a delay.

Comment: Listen to Michael, there is no such thing as applying too early for a visa.  But it's entirely possible that there would be a delay if you applied at the last minute (some obscure French holiday you've never heard of etc..)